# How to update a variable value returned from a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

This is my Quiz code for javascript:

```
"use strict"
const questions = [
  {
    question: "whats the full form of HTML",
    answers: {
      a: "Hello Text My Language",
      b: "Hyper text Main Language",
      c: "Hyper Text Markup Language",
      d: "Hi There My Luck",
    },
    correctAnswer:"ent-c",
  },
  {
    question: "whats the full form of CSS",
    answers: {
      a: "Cascading Style Sheet",
      b: "City Site Section",
      c: "Cyber Section Stand",
      d: "CycleStand Section",
    },
    correctAnswer:"ent-a",
  },
  {
    question: "whats the full form of JSON",
    answers: {
      a: "Jest Oriented Note",
      b: "JavaScript Object Notation",
      c: "Javascript Organised Node",
      d: "Joomla Of Node",
    },
    correctAnswer:"ent-b",
  },
  {
    question: "whats the full form of SQL",
    answers: {
      a: "Super Query Language",
      b: "Sorted Queue Line",
      c: "Superior Query Language",
      d: "Structured Query Language",
    },
    correctAnswer:"ent-d",
  },
];

let quest = document.querySelector('.question');
let quizLIst = document.querySelector('.quiz');
const btn = document.querySelector('.submitBtn');
const scoreDiv = document.querySelector('.scoreCard');
let currentQuestion = 0;
let score=0;
const loadQuestion = () =>{
    quest.innerText="";
    quizLIst.innerHTML="";
    console.log(questions[currentQuestion].question);
    quest.innerText = questions[currentQuestion].question;
    const ansEntries = Object.entries(questions[currentQuestion].answers);
    for (const [getQ, getA] of ansEntries) {
        quizLIst.innerHTML += `
        <li><input type="radio" class="ansOptions" id="ent-${getQ}" name="ans" value="${getA}"/><label for="${getA}">${getA}</label></</li>
        `;
    }
}
loadQuestion();

const allAnss = document.querySelectorAll('.ansOptions');
let getCheckedAnswer = () =>{
    let answer="";
    allAnss.forEach((currAns) =>{
        if(currAns.checked){
            answer = currAns.id;   
        }
    });
    return answer;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
   let checkedAnswer =  getCheckedAnswer();
    console.log("checked answer is ", checkedAnswer);
    if(checkedAnswer === questions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer){
        console.log("right");   
        score++;
    } 
    else{
        console.log("wrong");
    }
    currentQuestion++;
    
    if(currentQuestion <= questions.length){
        loadQuestion();
    }
})
```

But somehow checkedAnswer variable is not getting updated. After first question, checkedAnswer value is not getting empty, therefore my next answers are stuck with the first answer. where can i empty the checkedAnswer value in the code, i tried doing it, but nothing seemed to be working

Comment: Is it a coincidence that you wrote "Joomla Of Node" in your snippet?  Do you do Joomla work?  If so, we'd love to see you join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the current options contained in your `.ansOptions`. So you need to update  `getCheckedAnswer()` for each question, as `allAnss` is still containing the old NodeList from the first question's options.

```js
"use strict"
const questions = [
  {
    question: "whats the full form of HTML",
    answers: {
      a: "Hello Text My Language",
      b: "Hyper text Main Language",
      c: "Hyper Text Markup Language",
      d: "Hi There My Luck",
    },
    correctAnswer:"ent-c",
  },
  {
    question: "whats the full form of CSS",
    answers: {
      a: "Cascading Style Sheet",
      b: "City Site Section",
      c: "Cyber Section Stand",
      d: "CycleStand Section",
    },
    correctAnswer:"ent-a",
  },
  {
    question: "whats the full form of JSON",
    answers: {
      a: "Jest Oriented Note",
      b: "JavaScript Object Notation",
      c: "Javascript Organised Node",
      d: "Joomla Of Node",
    },
    correctAnswer:"ent-b",
  },
  {
    question: "whats the full form of SQL",
    answers: {
      a: "Super Query Language",
      b: "Sorted Queue Line",
      c: "Superior Query Language",
      d: "Structured Query Language",
    },
    correctAnswer:"ent-d",
  },
];

let quest = document.querySelector('.question');
let quizLIst = document.querySelector('.quiz');
const btn = document.querySelector('.submitBtn');
const scoreDiv = document.querySelector('.scoreCard');
let currentQuestion = 0;
let score=0;
const loadQuestion = () =>{
    quest.innerText="";
    quizLIst.innerHTML="";
    console.log(questions[currentQuestion].question);
    quest.innerText = questions[currentQuestion].question;
    const ansEntries = Object.entries(questions[currentQuestion].answers);
    for (const [getQ, getA] of ansEntries) {
        quizLIst.innerHTML += `
        <li><input type="radio" class="ansOptions" id="ent-${getQ}" name="ans" value="${getA}"/><label for="${getA}">${getA}</label></</li>
        `;
    }
}
loadQuestion();

let getCheckedAnswer = () =>{
    const allAnss = document.querySelectorAll('.ansOptions')
    let answer="";
    allAnss.forEach((currAns) =>{
        if(currAns.checked){
            answer = currAns.id;   
        }
    });
    return answer;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
   let checkedAnswer =  getCheckedAnswer();
    if(checkedAnswer === questions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer){
        console.log("right");   
        ++score;
    } else {
        console.log("wrong");
    }
    currentQuestion++;
    
    if(currentQuestion < questions.length){
        loadQuestion();
    }    
    document.querySelector('.scoreCard').innerText = 'Your score is ' + score + '.';
})
```

```html
<div class="scoreCard"></div>

<div class="question"></div>
<div class="quiz"></div>
<button class="submitBtn">answer</button>
```

Comment: Works perfect bro!! Thanks. but want to understand why i need to write const allAnss = document.querySelectorAll('.ansOptions'); this line in getCheckedAnswer function.

Comment: Because `allAnss` is having the list of elements returned from querySelectorAll **when it ran**. Why its different from other querySelector is that, here you are creating the `<li>` dynamically. But after you have created the new `li`s, you are not updating the reference in `allAnss`. So, it still has old value.